# julia magic in python notebook

Tags: python, julia

I am following the steps to embed Julia in Python notebooks [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-embed-your-julia-code-into-python-to-speed-up-performance-e3ff0a94b6e)

I installed Julia, installed PyJulia, and installed all the packages that PyJulia requires from Julia.
In a notebook, I typed `%load_ext julia.magic` and returned the following error. Similar error with `jl = Julia(compiled_modules=False)`.

I am not sure at all what the problem is, can someone please explain?

NOTE: I only have issue in Jupyter notebooks. I can run `jl = Julia(compiled_modules=False)` in IPython terminal but I cannot run this command in notebook.

```
Initializing Julia interpreter. This may take some time...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a49715008785> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('load_ext', 'julia.magic')

~/conda/envs/julia-py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2342                 kwargs['local_ns'] = self.get_local_scope(stack_depth)
   2343             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2344                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2345             return result
   2346 

~/conda/envs/julia-py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decorator.py in fun(*args, **kw)
    230             if not kwsyntax:
    231                 args, kw = fix(args, kw, sig)
--> 232             return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
    233     fun.__name__ = func.__name__
    234     fun.__signature__ = sig

~/conda/envs/julia-py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/conda/envs/julia-py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.py in load_ext(self, module_str)
     31         if not module_str:
     32             raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
---> 33         res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
     34 
     35         if res == 'already loaded':

~/conda/envs/julia-py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.py in load_extension(self, module_str)
     85                               dir=compress_user(self.ipython_extension_dir)))
     86             mod = sys.modules[module_str]
---> 87             if self._call_load_ipython_extension(mod):
     88                 self.loaded.add(module_str)
     89             else:

~/conda/envs/julia-py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.py in _call_load_ipython_extension(self, mod)
    132     def _call_load_ipython_extension(self, mod):
    133         if hasattr(mod, 'load_ipython_extension'):
--> 134             mod.load_ipython_extension(self.shell)
    135             return True
    136 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/julia/magic.py in load_ipython_extension(ip)
    156     # This is equivalent to `ip.register_magics(JuliaMagics)` (but it
    157     # let us access the instance of `JuliaMagics`):
--> 158     magics = JuliaMagics(shell=ip)
    159     ip.register_magics(magics)
    160 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/julia/magic.py in __init__(self, shell)
     98         # Flush, otherwise the Julia startup will keep stdout buffered
     99         sys.stdout.flush()
--> 100         self._julia = Julia(init_julia=True)
    101         print()
    102 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/julia/core.py in __init__(self, init_julia, jl_init_path, runtime, jl_runtime_path, debug, **julia_options)
    466             self.api = get_libjulia()
    467         elif init_julia:
--> 468             jlinfo = JuliaInfo.load(runtime)
    469             if jlinfo.version_info < (0, 7):
    470                 raise RuntimeError("PyJulia does not support Julia < 0.7 anymore")

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/julia/juliainfo.py in load(cls, julia, **popen_kwargs)
     66             os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "juliainfo.jl"
     67         )
---> 68         proc = subprocess.Popen(
     69             [julia, "--startup-file=no", juliainfo_script],
     70             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,

~/conda/envs/julia-py38/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    856                             encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
    857 
--> 858             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    859                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,
    860                                 startupinfo, creationflags, shell,

~/conda/envs/julia-py38/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1704                     if errno_num != 0:
   1705                         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1706                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1707                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1708 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'julia'
```

Error with running `jl = Julia(compiled_modules=False)`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-79df07b086bd> in <module>
      1 from julia import Julia
----> 2 jl = Julia(compiled_modules=False)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/julia/core.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    678 
    679     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 680         self.__julia = Julia(*args, **kwargs)
    681 
    682     __init__.__doc__ = Julia.__init__.__doc__

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/julia/core.py in __init__(self, init_julia, jl_init_path, runtime, jl_runtime_path, debug, **julia_options)
    466             self.api = get_libjulia()
    467         elif init_julia:
--> 468             jlinfo = JuliaInfo.load(runtime)
    469             if jlinfo.version_info < (0, 7):
    470                 raise RuntimeError("PyJulia does not support Julia < 0.7 anymore")

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/julia/juliainfo.py in load(cls, julia, **popen_kwargs)
     66             os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "juliainfo.jl"
     67         )
---> 68         proc = subprocess.Popen(
     69             [julia, "--startup-file=no", juliainfo_script],
     70             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,

~/conda/envs/julia-py38/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    856                             encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
    857 
--> 858             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    859                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,
    860                                 startupinfo, creationflags, shell,

~/conda/envs/julia-py38/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1704                     if errno_num != 0:
   1705                         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1706                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1707                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1708 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'julia'
```

Comment: Have you added the julia binary to your PATH environment variable? Look at [this](https://julialang.org/downloads/platform/).

Comment: I already had added it to my .bashrc like `export PATH="$PATH:/home/myself/julia-1.6.2/bin"` and restarted the session. I've also updated the question to isolate the problem with just notebooks.

Comment: Did that actually work? You can check from within your notebook with `import os; os.getenv('PATH')`.

Comment: Oh you're correct, it's not in the PATH! How do I fix this?